# Autostarting a script at boot doesn't recognize the function "function"

Tags: linux, shell-script, sh

I'm trying to get a script containing a function to run just after root autologin on TinyCore 5.3. The script works fine if I launch it from the prompt after login like this ./script.sh
But when I add the line to run the script from root's .profile file, I get the following error:

> /opt/script.sh: line 3: function: not found
>
> [1]+ Stopped (tty output) sudo su -c "/opt/script.sh" -s /bin/ash root

I get the same error even if I call the file with just "./opt/script.sh"
instead of "sudo su -c "/opt/script.sh" -s /bin/ash root" (I've also tried /bin/sh)

**Since the script work fine if I start it manually I'm guessing that I'm not telling the right script interpreter to run the script, but instead it is started by an interpreter that doesn't understand the "function" function.**

I've tried to change #!/bin/sh in the script to #!bin/ash but it doesn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ash is a very stripped down shell. It probably does not support the syntax

```
function myFuncname { ...; }
```

Use this instead

```
myFuncname() { ...; }
```

Comment: Then how come it works when i just do a ./script.sh after login?

Comment: Does it work like this: `/bin/ash ./script.sh` ?